# docker-compose.yml spark/hadoop/hive for three data nodes

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, docker-compose, hive

This `docker-compose.yml` with one `datanode` seems to work ok:

```
version: "3"

services:
  namenode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: namenode
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9010:9000
    volumes:
      - hadoop_namenode:/hadoop/dfs/name
    environment:
      - CLUSTER_NAME=test
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
      CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS: hdfs://namenode:9000
    ports:
      - "9864:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  resourcemanager:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-resourcemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: resourcemanager
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  nodemanager1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-nodemanager:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: nodemanager
    restart: always
    environment:

      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  historyserver:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-historyserver:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: historyserver
    restart: always
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9000 namenode:9870 datanode:9864 resourcemanager:8088"
    volumes:
      - hadoop_historyserver:/hadoop/yarn/timeline
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:3.0.0-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-master
    depends_on:
      - namenode
      - datanode
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000

  spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:3.0.0-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
      - CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:9000

  hive-server:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    container_name: hive-server
    depends_on:
      - namenode
      - datanode
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    environment:
      HIVE_CORE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL: "jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore/metastore"
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "hive-metastore:9083"
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"

  hive-metastore:
    image: bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore
    container_name: hive-metastore
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop-hive.env
    command: /opt/hive/bin/hive --service metastore
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870 datanode:9864 hive-metastore-postgresql:5432"
    ports:
      - "9083:9083"

  hive-metastore-postgresql:
    image: bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql:2.3.0
    container_name: hive-metastore-postgresql

  presto-coordinator:
    image: shawnzhu/prestodb:0.181
    container_name: presto-coordinator
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"

volumes:
  hadoop_namenode:
  hadoop_datanode:
  hadoop_historyserver:
```

I want to modify it so that it uses three `datanodes`. I tried adding this right below the original `datanode` section, but it seems to not like it. It basically adds new names, and new ports:

```
  datanode1:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
      CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS: hdfs://namenode:9000
    ports:
      - "9865:9865"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env

  datanode2:
    image: bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop3.2.1-java8
    container_name: datanode2
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - hadoop_datanode:/hadoop/dfs/data
    environment:
      SERVICE_PRECONDITION: "namenode:9870"
      CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS: hdfs://namenode:9000
    ports:
      - "9866:9866"
    env_file:
      - ./hadoop.env
```

Should this work, and if not, what do I need to change to get three `datanodes` ?

Comment: https://clubhouse.io/developer-how-to/how-to-set-up-a-hadoop-cluster-in-docker/

Comment: More than one datanode on one machine won't really provide any improvements over a single one

Answer (score 1):

Check your `ports` setting. It seems that the port mapping is faulty. You have "9865:9865" (datanode1) and "9866:9866" (datanode2).

Try setting it to "9865:9864" and "9866:9864" respectively, as 9864 is the default port that the datanode is using, and the first port number defines how the datanode shall be reachable outside the docker network.

With the suggested configuration, your datanodes will be reachable on datanode:9864 (datanode1:9864, datanode2:9864) from within the network, and on :9864 (and :9865, :9866) from outside the docker network.